# Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of positive reals, show that $\limsup\sqrt[n] {x_n}\leq\limsup \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $\{x_n\}$  be a sequence of positive reals, show that $\limsup\sqrt[n] {x_n}\leq\limsup \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$.

This come from a problem set, in which $\limsup{\sum^{n}_{i=1}\frac {x_n}n}\leq\limsup {x_n}$ is proved in previous question. I am not sure if it is related, as I tried AM-GM, but nothing works.

Comment: Consider that $x_n = {x_n \over x_{n-1}}{x_{n-1}\over x_{n-2}}\cdots{x_2\over x_1}$

Comment: @ dan: is RHS of your equation missing a $x_1$?

Comment: @JASON: Yes it is but that doesn't really change anything. after some finite number of terms on the far right, everything is less than $\limsup\frac{x_n+1}{x_n}+\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon$

Comment: Ahhhh I didn't know to get rid of the $x_1$ so I failed. Now I get it, thanks.

Comment: In the above coment I meant to write $\limsup{x_{n+1}\over x_n}+\epsilon$ and note that the finite number of terms on the far right depends on $\epsilon$

Comment: err... actually why is after finite humber of terms, everything is less than $\limsup{x_{n+1}}/{x_n}+\epsilon$? the $x_1/x_2$ can be arbitrarily large....

Answer (score 1):

If $\limsup (x_{n+1}/x_n) \rightarrow \infty$ then there's nothing to be done. If not, define

$$a = \limsup\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$$

Now, choose $b>a$. There is a $n_o\in\mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} \leq b \hspace{1em}\textrm{for all}\hspace{0.5em} n\geq n_o $$

So we have $x_{n+1} \leq bx_n$ for all $n\geq n_o$.

Hence $x_{n_o+p}\leq b^p x_{n_o}$ for $p>0$, $p\in\mathbb{N}$.
So writing $n=n_o +p$ we have $x_n\leq b^{n-n_o}x_{n_o} $, so we have:

$$x_n \leq (b^{-n_o}x_{n_o})b^n \hspace{1em}\textrm{for all}\hspace{0.5em} n\geq n_o $$

Thus

$$\sqrt[n]{x_n} \leq b\sqrt[n]{(b^{-n_o}x_{n_o})} \hspace{1em}\textrm{for all}\hspace{0.5em} n\geq n_o $$

Therefore

$$\limsup \sqrt[n]{x_n} \leq b  $$

Since this is true for all $b>a$ we have:

$$\limsup \sqrt[n]{x_n} \leq a = \limsup\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}  $$